# Running Update on Android SQLiteDatabase without DatabaseHelper

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Trying to simple update a row in an SQLiteDatabase Database. I can insert records fine with:

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + table + " (Date, Urine, Def, Flat, Snez, Mus)" + " VALUES     ('" + dat + "', " + uri + ", " + def + ", " + fl + ", " + sn + ", " + mu + ");");
```

But when I try to update a row with:

```
myDB.execSQL("UPDATE " + TableMain + " SET " + field+ "=" + number + "WHERE Date = "+ DateMaker(today)+";");
```

I get a "Database Not Open" error in LogCat. So I try to open the database with:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=myDB.getWritableDatabase();
```

But I'm told by eclipse that getWritableDatabase() is undefined, so I tried:

```
myDB.openDatabase("myDB", null, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But then I'm greeted with the error "Unable to open Database File". So I changed the path to data/data/com.BodyTracker/database so..:

```
myDB.openDatabase("data/data/com.BodyTracker/database", null, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And I once again get unable to open database error. I don't know why it can't open it, it can write to and read from the database, it just won't update. This is all happening in my main activity, which extends TabActivity, not SQLiteDatabase. I'm not using DatabaseHelper, I'm new to this and it's too complicated for my simple needs (reading in and out 6 values, and updating them).

Where I create the database:

```
   myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
     /* Create a Table in the Database. */
     myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
       + TableMain
       + " (Date VARCHAR, Urine INT(3), Def INT(3), Flat INT(3), Snez INT(3), Mus INT(3));");
```

My Update Code:

```
public int UpdateDB(String field, int number)
{
 //SQLiteDatabase db=myDB.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
 cv.put("Urine", number);
 cv.put("Def", number);
 cv.put("Flat", number);
 cv.put("Snez", number);
 cv.put("Mus", number);
 cv.put("Date", DateMaker(today));
 
 myDB.openDatabase("data/data/com.BodyTracker/database", null, MODE_PRIVATE);
 
 
// myDB.rawQuery("UPDATE " + TableMain + " SET " + field+ "=" + number + "WHERE Date =? ", new String[]{DateMaker(today)});
// myDB.execSQL("UPDATE " + TableMain + " SET " + field+ "=" + number + "WHERE Date = "+ DateMaker(today)+";");
 return myDB.update(TableMain, cv, "Date=?", new String[]{DateMaker(today)});   
 
}
```

Please ask for other info, this is my first question so not 100% what exactly to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) command

Comment: In my last block of code above i am using (among other, commented out attempts) the Update command. It fails with either Database not open, or unable to open database, depending on weather myDB.openDatabase is commented or not. I think the problem lies with the opening of the database.

Comment: can you check that the database is really created in the app's folder at
/data/data/yourapp/databases

Comment: Yes its there, i can navigate to it and even open the tables and see the data. Its defiantly there.

Comment: Try openning it with the static method like this: 

`SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
     SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that. My database is already created, so i don't want a new one called db. And i already have tried myDB.openDatabse

Comment: How do you create your database? This function does not create a new database it opens the database at the path and returns a **database object**.

Can you post the code on how the initializtion of myDB occurs?

Comment: Just tried it again after understand waht you eman and how to use your previous answer and still got the "unable to open database file"

Code:

SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("databases", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
 
db.update(TableMain, cv, "Date=?", new String[]{DateMaker(today)});

Comment: So it looks like you are trying to open the database twice.. Can you post the complete code.

Comment: Yet if i don't run an openDatabase command of any kind, it errors because of "database not open". I don't think i can paste all the code into this comment box? its about 550 lines (i'm a very sloppy programm[ing student]er, all my code and methods are in 1 .java file).

And anyway, i have given you all code relating to the database in the question, except how i declare it:

SQLiteDatabase myDB= null;

Comment: Solved it. had to do:
myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("DatabaseName", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Before i ran the update. A day and a half of confusion for that! Nevermind. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you should not use `data/data/com.BodyTracker/database` you simply need to use `database`

Also, you seem to be missing a SQLiteOpenHelpe extended class
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#sqliteoverview_sqliteopenhelper

**Also, a little tip**
Use prepared statements for inserts

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE bar = ?");
stmt.bindString(1, "foobar");
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: i tried with with just database:

        myDB.openDatabase("database", null, MODE_PRIVATE);

But that didn't work either, same unable to open error. Also, id really rather not use the Helper class, I've got everything but this last thing working in my app, and id really rather not have to learn how to use the new class and change my app accordingly. Of course i will if needs be, but id rather not. I really think the problem is with opening up the database.